# Why is os.path.getmtime() always running twice? It does not make any sense

Tags: python, asynchronous, last-modified

Here is the code:

```
import os
import asyncio
async def func_placing_sell_orders():
    prev_final_stocks_list_state = os.path.getmtime('stock_data//final_stocks_list.json')
    print('i run once')
    while True:
        if (prev_final_stocks_list_state != os.path.getmtime('stock_data//final_stocks_list.json')):
            prev_final_stocks_list_state = os.path.getmtime('stock_data//final_stocks_list.json')
            print('here')

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(func_placing_sell_orders())
```

simplified ver:

```
import os
def simple():
    state = os.path.getmtime('file.json')
    print('i run once')
    while True:
        if (state != os.path.getmtime('file.json')):
            state = os.path.getmtime('file.json')
            print('here')

simple()
```

This is the print out:

```
i run once
here
here
```

***here***, gets print out twice every time I save the file. I ran to check the time between previous and  current modified time and it is always different, which implies it should only run once per save.

This is so basic I don't understand why I'm getting this result. Please send help

Comment: I'm somewhat surprised it *only* runs twice, since it's being called in an infinite loop... I don't understand why you're using an `async` function either, there's nothing async in your function.

Comment: It's not a response, it's a comment that the code does not match the error being reported, meaning the request for help is incoherent. Furthermore the example code simply can not be run. Assisting with issues when 10% of the relevant information is present and 90% is missing is difficult.

Comment: @the_begging_beginner Try to be a bit more polite. *You* are the one asking for help.

Comment: Something else is modifying the file. When I run your simplified example as shown (with `while True` replaced with `for _ in range(10)`, I don't see `'here'` printed *at all*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file is large enough maybe the first "here" is while file is still writing edits and the last "here" is after the saving is done. Also, if you're using something like `open("file", "w")` or something like this to write edits, the file will be first clean (first "here") and then edited with with new data (second "here")

You can ignore too fast reports (<1s) with a simple timer

```
lastEdit = time.time()
while True:
    if (state != os.path.getmtime('file.json')):
        state = os.path.getmtime('file.json')
        if time.time()-lastEdit > 1: 
            print('here')
        lastEdit = time.time()
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. I didnt know that a file size changes the behavior like this. Is there a way to mitigate it (i.e. ensure only one run through)?

Comment: Added possible solution